# How I can Put my all Django Admin posts to my localhost View?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

**My Recent Post in Django Administration**
Kamran object (4)
Kamran object (3)
Kamran object (2)
Kamran object (1)

**How I can show these posts in my localhost View?**

Comment: this question is very unclear. You created posts via django/admin and want to show them on the frontend?

Comment: yes I want to show on frontend

Comment: please post your model and view, then we can provide you a template solution